# How to insert array embedded inside a postgresql custom type

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I have defined a new type

```
 CREATE TYPE days_of_week as (
    days integer[]
  );
```

I have a table as follows:

```
 create table rr( idd days_of_Week);
```

I am trying to insert an array in days_of_week like

```
insert into rr ( idd ) VALUES ( ('{1,3}') );
```

I get an error: `ERROR:  malformed record literal: "{1,3}"`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use this one;

```
insert into rr ( idd ) VALUES ( row('{1,3}')::days_of_week );
```

Also,

```
insert into rr ( idd ) VALUES ( row('{1,3}') );
```